# How to draw borders for TextView created using Code not by XML in Android

Tags: android

I created my TextView through code rather than XML. I want to draw a border around the  TextView.How can we do this using code rather than XML? I also wanted when I try to setText for the TextView which is of some 2 lines then TextView is moving downward? plz also guide me to solve this problem.
I will be waititng for reply . 
Regarda,

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to get a nice border to your text view would be to create a 9-patch image and set it as background to your text field. Just get padding right in your image and you have a border for your text view

I don't really understand your second question. Would setting your text field as a single line help?
[link to TextView API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine%28%29)

Comment: How can I set the text in the center of a image??