# how to set textview border dynamically in android

Tags: android

I m newbie to android and i am working on an app in which i want to set the border of textview dynamically, i.e by code not by xml. i searched a lot on google but everywhere i find solution by xml. I tried a lot, but didn't find a correct way to implement this.
Like using this url, but i cant get to the result
[How to draw borders for TextView created using Code not by XML in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922571/how-to-draw-borders-for-textview-created-using-code-not-by-xml-in-android)
please suggest me ideas,how i can achieve this..

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you wont find much documentation about non-XML layouts is because most problems can be solved with the layouts. I would suggest at least defining the textview in the XML, then setting the border later in code. For example:

*In the layout.xml file:*

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
```

*Then in your code:*

```
TextView text = ((TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text)); //use id to find view
ViewGroup.LayoutParams textLayout = text.getLayoutParams();
textLayout.topMargin = 10;
textLayout.bottomMargin = 10;
text.setLayoutParams(textLayout);
```

You can modify any attribute of the object this way. (use [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) as a resource)

Note the above examples are just examples (I don't have a compiler in front of me to check syntax and effectiveness)